# Changes to object made with Object.assign mutates source object

Tags: javascript, redux, immutability

I have following reducer code in my react-redux app:

```
    case 'TOGGLE_CLIENT_SELECTION':
        const id = action.payload.id;
        let newState = Object.assign({}, state);
        newState.list.forEach((client) => {
            if (client.id == id) client.selected = !client.selected;
        });
        console.log(state.list[0].selected + ' - ' + newState.list[0].selected)
        return newState;
```

If I got it right - Object.assign creates brand new object, but console.log displays "true - true" of "false - false". Any thoughts why it behaves like this and how can I avoid this behavior?

Comment: Object.assign won't do deep cloning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

True, but it's not a deep copy.

The new object contains a reference to the old list.

Here's a trick to get around it (there's more "proper" ways some might say):

JSON.stringify the original. Then JSON.parse that string. The new object will be a "deep" copy (not sure if that's really technically "deep copying"). It works fine unless your sub-types are something more complex than standard plain old JSON-acceptable stuff.

Comment: This seems to work, so I'll use it for now. But what do you mean by 'proper' ways?

Comment: Well, it assumes you are certain that the thing you are trying to deep copy can in fact be deep copied by converting it to JSON. For example, say you had an array of Maps that use Symbols as keys. This wouldn't work, because Symbols are ignored by .stringify. Also, custom types, depending on how "custom" they are, could fail. A really robust deep copier would take everything into account, or at least, have guards and use substitutes and/or issue some kind of report of what couldn't be copied, producing a usable (though incomplete) deep copied object. But for me, this has always done the trick.

Comment: So, for complex data structures I would need to create my own copying function? Anyway, I got it and your method works for me, so I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Yes I believe recursive relationships can now managed in JSON via some extra libs, don't think it's part of the standard yet but I remember using something a while back to solve a JSON recursion error. Quick search brings up: http://springquay.blogspot.com/2016/01/new-approach-to-solve-json-recursive.html

Answer (score 12):

### `Object.assign({}, ...)` creates a shallow clone

`Object.assign({}, state)` will copy properties from `state`. String, number and boolean properties are copied "by value", while object properties (including Dates) are "by reference", which means the new properties point to the same objects as the old properties.

So, for example, given:

```js
const otherState = { count: 10 };

const state = {
  text: "foo",
  otherState: otherState,
};

const newState = Object.assign({}, state);

newState.text = "bar";
newState.otherState.count = 9;
```

`newState.text` will have a brand new string assigned to it, and state will not be affected. But both `state` and `newState` refer to the same instance of `otherState`, so when you updated `count` to 9, both `state.otherState.count` and `newState.otherState.count` are affected:

```
state = {
  text = "foo"
  otherState ──────┐
}                  │
                   │
                   │
                   ├────> { count = 9 }
                   │
newState = {       │
  text = "bar"     │
  otherState ──────┘
}
```

When using `Object.assign`, use the rule of three: if you get to the third property, you are now working in "shared" state:

```
newState.otherState.count = 0;
//  ^        ^        ^
//  ╵        ╵        ╵
//  1        2        3
```

### JSON.parse to the rescue (?)

A quick and easy work around, as [suggested by Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43074256/changes-to-object-made-with-object-assign-mutates-source-object/43074291#43074291), is to use JSON.stringify:

```
let newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
```

But this is not foolproof. It'll work for some simple scenarios, but there are many scenarios that might fail. For example, circular references break JSON.stringify:

```js
let x = { id: "x" },
y = { id: "y" };
x.y = y;
y.x = x;

// fails with: "Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"
let cloneX = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x));
```

### Custom cloning code to the rescue (?)

If you know the structure that you're trying to clone, then you can use your own logic to handle the copying and not fall into endless loops:

```js
function cloneX( x ){
    const c_x = { id: x.id };
    const c_y = { id: x.y.id };
    c_x.y = c_y;
    c_y.x = c_x;
    return c_x;
}

let x = { id: "x" },
    y = { id: "y" };
x.y = y;
y.x = x;

let x2 = cloneX(x);
x2.y.id = "y2";

console.log( `x2.y.id was updated: ${x2.y.id}` );
console.log( `x.y.id is unchanged: ${x.y.id}` );
```

It's also conceivable that, with some creative use of [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap), you could come up with some logic that handles unknown data structures by tracking recursion and allowing deep copies.

### NPM to the rescue (?)

It'd probably be easier to just [use a library](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords:deep-copy), though.

Comment: Thanks, I got it.

Comment: @ElaginVladislav If you already have jQuery in your project, you can use `extend` to perform a deep copy for you by passing `true` as the first argument. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

Comment: The post says with big letters that "Object.assign creates a shallow clone". It's important to note, though, that it creates a shallow clone of ONLY the second argument. It returns the same object it takes as the first argument, so it's essentially mutating function, not copying.

Comment: @GolDDranks - That's a good point. Maybe I'll change it to "Object.assign() is not a deep clone"

Answer (score 2):

Try this : `let newState = state.map(item => Object.assign({}, ...item))` 
This will create a new object without any reference to the old object `state`

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign, `Object.assign` modifies the `target` object rather than creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to make a deep copy and then use `Object.asign` with it:

```js
const x = { id: "x" },
y = { id: "y" };
x.y = y;
y.x = x;
const cloneX = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(x));

const cloneChangeX = Object.assign(cloneX, {z: {id: "z"}});

console.log('const x = ', x, '\nconst cloneX = ', cloneX, '\nconst cloneChangeX = ', cloneChangeX);
```

Finally, you can do:

```
const cloneChangeX = Object.assign(
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(x)),
  { changekey: changevalue }
);
```

Comment: or even easier: Object.assign({...source}, target);