# Using Object Assign to clear state

Tags: javascript, object, vue.js, vuex

This is my state:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    items: [
    ],
    user: {
      isAuthenticated: false,
      info: {
        createdAt: '',
        email: '',
        firstName: '',
        id: '',
        lastName: '',
      },
      token: {
        accessToken: '',
        expiresIn: '',
        refreshToken: '',
        tokenType: '',
      },
    },
  },
  actions,
  mutations,
  getters,
  plugins: [createPersistedState({
    key: 'persistedState',
    paths: ['user'],
  })],
  strict: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
});
```

I keep separately the default state of user - so I don't have to manually reset every property when necessary.

```
export const defaultUser = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  info: {
    createdAt: '',
    email: '',
    firstName: '',
    id: '',
    lastName: '',
  },
  token: {
    accessToken: '',
    expiresIn: '',
    refreshToken: '',
    tokenType: '',
  },
};
```

So, when a logout action is triggered:

```
export const logout = ({ commit, dispatch }) => {
  commit(types.LOGOUT_USER);
  dispatch('changeStatus', 'You need to login or register.');
};



[types.LOGOUT_USER](state) {
  Object.assign(state.user, defaultUser);
},
```

but magically sometimes the entire user object seems to not have been replaced... (or the defaultState object is filled with the last values?)

Comment: not going to post as an answer because I'm not in the vue world, but this use of `Object.assign` will mutate `state.user`. You might want `Object.assign({}, state.user, defaultUser)` ?

Comment: yep, the file is called "mutations" :) https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html it's how its supposed to happen (I know Redux does it differently and I was also wondering in the beginning)

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the other answers:
Essentially this question is an indirect duplicate of [Changes to object made with Object.assign mutates source object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43074256/changes-to-object-made-with-object-assign-mutates-source-object).

`Object.assign` is safe to use for a max of 2 levels of nesting.

For example `Object.assign(myObj.firstProp, myDefaultObj.firstProp);`

Taken from the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

> Warning for Deep Clone For deep cloning, we need to use other
>   alternatives because Object.assign() copies property values. If the
>   source value is a reference to an object, it only copies that
>   reference value.